# swift - retrieving data from realtime database failed

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data from a Firebase realtime database. I can see the data in the Firebase Console but I don't see the data in my app.

this is the structure of the database:
users -> someUserIDs -> items -> someItemIDs -> detailsOfTheItem.

in my DatabaseManager class:

```
    static var shared = DatabaseManager()

    private let databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    func saveItem(_ item: InventoryItem, path: String) {
        let itemRef = databaseRef.child(path).child(item.id)
        itemRef.setValue(item.dictionaryRepresentation())
        
    }

    func fetchItems(path: String, completion: @escaping ([InventoryItem]) -> ()) {
        
        let itemsRef = databaseRef.child(path)
        
        itemsRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
                print("No items data found")
                completion([])
                return
            }
        
            var items = [InventoryItem]()
            for (_, itemData) in value {
                guard let itemDict = itemData as? [String: Any],
                      let itemID = itemDict["itemID"] as? String,
                      let name = itemDict["name"] as? String,
                      let itemPrice = itemDict["itemPrice"] as? Double,
                      let itemQuantity = itemDict["itemQuantity"] as? Int,
                      let size = itemDict["size"] as? String,
                      let AdditionDateTimestamp = itemDict["AdditionDate"] as? Double,
                      let itemNotes = itemDict["itemNotes"] as? String

                else {
                    continue
                }

                let AdditionDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: AdditionDateTimestamp)
            
                let item = InventoryItem(
                     itemID: itemID,
                     name: name,
                     itemPrice: itemPrice,
                     itemQuantity: itemQuantity,
                     size: size,
                     AdditionDate: AdditionDate,
                     itemNotes: itemNotes
            )
            
            items.append(item)
        }
        
        completion(items)
    })
}
```

In my InventoryManager class I'm saving and fetching the data like that:

```
class InventoryManager: ObservableObject {
    
    static var shared = InventoryManager()
    @Published var items: [InventoryItem] = []
    private var isUserSignedIn = Auth.auth().currentUser != nil

    func fetchItemsFromDB() {
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            let userID = currentUser.uid
            print("Current UserID: \(userID)")
            let path = "users/\(userID)/items"

            DatabaseManager.shared.fetchItems(path: path, completion: { fetchedItems in
                self.items = fetchedItems
            })
        }
    }

    func saveItem2DB(_ item: InventoryItem) {
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
           let userID = currentUser.uid
           let path = "users/\(userID)/items"
           DatabaseManager.shared.saveItem(item, path: path)
        }
    }

    func addItem(item: InventoryItem) {
        items.append(item)
        if isUserSignedIn{
            saveItem2DB(item)
        }
        else{
            saveItems2UD()
        }
    }
```

I initialize in the ContentView and display it in InventoryContentView. It worked fine when I was using UserDefaults but when I added the realtime database it didn't.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var inventoryManager = InventoryManager.shared
    @State private var isUserSignedIn = Auth.auth().currentUser != nil
    init() {
        if isUserSignedIn {
            InventoryManager.shared.fetchItemsFromDB()
        }
        else {
            InventoryManager.shared.loadItemsFromUD()
        }
    }
...
}
```

```
struct InventoryContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var inventoryManager: InventoryManager
    ...
    var filteredItems: [InventoryItem] {
        if searchText.isEmpty {
            return Array(inventoryManager.getItems())
        } else {
            return Array(inventoryManager.getItems().filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) })
        }
    }
    

    var body: some View {
    ...
 if inventoryItems.isEmpty {
                        Text("No inventory items yet")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        List(sortedItems) { item in  // sortedItems gets its data from filteredItems
                            
                            NavigationLink(destination: ItemDetailsView(inventoryManager: inventoryManager, item: item))
                            {
                                VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                                    Text("Name: \(item.name)")
                                    Text("Price: \(item.itemPrice, specifier: "%.2f")")
                                    Text("Q: \(item.itemQuantity)")
                                }
                            }
         ...
        }
   var inventoryItems: [InventoryItem] {
        return inventoryManager.items
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Is `else { continue }` called? You need to see which part of your code is called or not (breakpoints, print).

Comment: I checked now and it seems like `else { continue }`  is called

Comment: You have 16 tests in the `guard let` that if any of them fails you'll get `continue` and then skipped. So determine which one(s) fail(s). On the `guard`, for `let itemID = itemDict["itemID"] as? String`, it will fails if `itemDict["itemID"]` is `nil`, and if it's not nil, it will fail if it's not a `String`. So check the all of them, as any of them failing will trigger the `else`.

Comment: can you show the code where you display the data in your view, since this is where your problem is, according to your question, `I can see the data in the Firebase Console but I don't see the data in my app.` In particular show how you declare your `InventoryManager` and how you use it or pass it to other views. If you put a `print` just before `completion(items)` do you get anything?

Comment: If you add `print("---> items: \(items)")` just before `completion(items)`
 in your `DatabaseManager` class, do you get anything?

Comment: I checked every 'let' and added the print statement and it seems to be because of the 'Date' variable. I'll try fixing it. thank you both :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> it seems like `else { continue }` is called

You need to debug: Use breakpoints or add prints and see where your app really goes when it runs.

It seems that you enter the `continue` in the big:

```
guard let ... else { continue }
```

Let's just modify it to ensure that's the case:

```
guard let ... else { 
    print("Didn't pass the guard let, will continue")
    continue
}
```

Now, let's analyze your `guard let`:

```
let itemID = itemDict["itemID"] as? String
```

This means that `let itemID` will be `nil` and then you'll enter the `else` of the `guard let` in the following cases:
`itemDict["itemID"]` is `nil` OR `itemDict["itemID"]` is NOT `nil`, but isn't a `String`.

You have 7 tests for `nil`, and 8 tests for casts (`as?`). So here, you have potentially 15 possible reasons to hit the `else` (`continue`).

```
guard let itemDict = itemData as? [String: Any],
    let itemID = itemDict["itemID"] as? String,
    let name = itemDict["name"] as? String,
    let itemPrice = itemDict["itemPrice"] as? Double,
    let itemQuantity = itemDict["itemQuantity"] as? Int,
    let size = itemDict["size"] as? String,
    let AdditionDateTimestamp = itemDict["AdditionDate"] as? Double,
    let itemNotes = itemDict["itemNotes"] as? String
else {
    continue
}
```

So let's start debugging which one causes the issue.

If you use Breakpoints, in the console do:

```
po itemDict["itemID"] as? String
```

If it's `nil`, then do

```
po itemDict["itemID"]
```

If it is `nil`, it means that the value isn't there (wrong key?, can it be nil?), if not, it means that the cast (`as? String`) didn't work. So it's not a `String`.

Do the same for each one of them and find one or multiple culprits.

With just prints:

```
print("itemDict[\"itemID\"]: \(itemDict["itemID"])")
print("itemDict[\"itemID\"] as? String: \(itemDict["itemID"] as? String)")
... //Do all of them
```

See which one is `nil`, same reasoning as with `po` just before.

And find why one of the value is `nil`. We don't know your Firebase model, so we can't guess.

If the casts fails, check on your model which class it in reality, see modify your iOS model or transform the value if you can't before setting it into your model (example, if your Firebase model return an `Int` but you can it to use as a `String`, then convert that integer into a String, if that makes sense to your app).